# Tests not working anymore after updating to version < 24.0.0

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

Today, we've updated to the newest version of jest in our TypeScript project. We've included jest in our `package.json` of our project with`"jest": "^24.7.1"`. We've also included `"jest-when": "^2.4.0"`.

When we run now our tests, we get 1531 errors that jest wasn't found:

- `Cannot find name 'jest'.`
- `Cannot find name 'expect'.`
- `Cannot find name 'it'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try`npm i @types/jest`or`npm i @types/mocha`and then add`jest`or`mocha`to the types field in your tsconfig.`

and much more.

We include jest in our spec's with `import 'jest';` at the top.

Does anyone has an idea what could be the problem?

```sh
System:
    OS: macOS 10.14.3
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 11.10.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.13.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.7.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  npmPackages:
    jest: ^24.7.1 => 24.7.1
```

Comment: Have you done what the error message suggests, e.g., updating the type definitions?

Comment: Yes this is what I did

Comment: I had to go all the way back to 24.1.0 to get things working again. Are you testing Angular, by any chance?

Comment: The problem was that the @types/jest had the wrong version. The newest types and normal jest don't works together. I'll post an answer if I've found out the correct types version with the newest jest.